# SP2010 API: How to insert data into list with folders

Tags: 2010, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

I have used SPServices for a long time, both creating, deleting and getting list items from my sharepoint sites.

Now I got a new site, and in this site the previous developer has created lists with folders.

The structure for all 4 lists is like this: (This is just an example)

- Folder: Regional

  - Folder: Spain

    - Items....
- Folder: International

  - Folder: Europe

    - Items....
- Folder: Local

  - Folder: Department

    - Items....

In this exmaple: http://sympmarc.com/2011/03/28/listing-folders-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-with-spservices/ the guy shows how to display the folder structure when getting the list items.

But when using "UpdateListItems" how do I create folders and then add items to that folder?

I can use both SPServices.js and SP.js so I have no other requirement on how to do it, besides I need to be able to do it from Javascript. I'm only assigned the role of Web admin, so I do not have access to PowerShell, ServerSide code or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OOTB file upload facility** for SharePoint library using below url:

`https://sharepoint.contoso.com/sites/YourSiteUrl/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={Destination LIST GUID}&RootFolder="ServerRelativeURL of destination folder"`

**Note:** Upper mentioned url is working in SharePoint 2013. For SharePOint 2010, just open the library in IE browser --> click on "upload document" button, --> popup will be opened -->right click on that and click on properties and you will get proper url. It might be just 14 hive change in the URL.

---

### Create Folder using JSOM:

```
<div><button onclick=" createFolder ()">Click here to AddaFieldtoList</button></div>  

  <div id="displayDiv"></div>  
  <script type="text/javascript">   
  function createFolder() {  
    var clientContext;  
    var oWebsite;  
    var oList;  
    var itemCreateInfo;   

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");  

    itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
    itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);  
    itemCreateInfo.set_leafName("My new folder!");  
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
    this.oListItem.update();  

    clientContext.load(this.oListItem);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(  
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),  
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)  
    );  

    function successHandler() {  
        alert("New folder is created successfully!");  
    }  

    function errorHandler() {  alert("Error: "+arguments[1].get_message());
    }  
}  
</script>
```

### Add file to SharePoint Library using REST api:

```
function sendFileToServer(filename, file) 
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) 
    {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
        {
            var folder = localStorage.getItem('FolderName');

            var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'LibraryName/' + folder;
            var buffer = evt.target.result;
            //Upload to Specific folder 
            var docLibraryEndpoint = String.format( "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                            "/add(overwrite=true,url='{2}')",
                            _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, filename
                            );
            $.ajax({
                url: docLibraryEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: buffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success:function()
                {
                    alert("Document uploaded successfully");
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert("Failed to upload the document");
                }
            });
        }
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

**References:**

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-2016-javascript-object-model/
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-jsom/
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-create-a-file-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-js/
- [Upload document to a specific folder in a Document Library using JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191437/upload-document-to-a-specific-folder-in-a-document-library-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the "file" example as well, but its just simple items that I want to add to the specific folder :) Eg: How do I add an item to "Europe" from my example. Remember this needs to work in SP2010. Your references are for later versions of SharePoint :)

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Its super!! :) i'm sorry if I have been unclear. When I say "items" I mean in a custom list. Not a document library. :)

Comment: How can you create folders in the custom list and add items in the custom list?

Comment: yes - Exactly! I'm working with a custom list, which has folders, and in my project, I need to be able to extract all data from that list, then go to another SharePoint site and insert all the same data with the same structure in a new list. 
I will, of course, create the list on the new site and setup fields :)
It works perfectly the way I do it today, with SPServices, but since this list contains folders, it does not work anymore.